# Configurar GCC 12 al parecer el problema es en la carpeta torture

Tags: compilar, configuración, gcc

Quise compilar *GCC 12* con *GCC 11*, y no puede hacer el *./configure*.

- Binarios del *GCC 11*: https://copr-be.cloud.fedoraproject.org/results/jwakely/gcc-latest/opensuse-tumbleweed-x86_64/02088309-gcc-latest/
- Código fuente del *GCC 12*: https://bigsearcher.com/mirrors/gcc/snapshots/LATEST-12/

***./configure***

```
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /bin/ginstall -c
checking whether ln works... yes
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for gawk... gawk
checking for libatomic support... yes
checking for libitm support... yes
checking for libsanitizer support... yes
checking for libvtv support... yes
checking for libphobos support... yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/initrd/mnt/dev_save/sfs/gcc-12-20210530':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

El problema está en `./configure:4522`:

```
if test -z "$ac_file"; then :
  { $as_echo "$as_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: result: no" >&5
$as_echo "no" >&6; }
$as_echo "$as_me: failed program was:" >&5
sed 's/^/| /' conftest.$ac_ext >&5

{ { $as_echo "$as_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: error: in \`$ac_pwd':" >&5
$as_echo "$as_me: error: in \`$ac_pwd':" >&2;}
as_fn_error 77 "C compiler cannot create executables
See \`config.log' for more details" "$LINENO" 5; }
else
  { $as_echo "$as_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: result: yes" >&5
$as_echo "yes" >&6; }
fi
```

Cuando hago `$ac_files` veo lo siguiente:

```
a.out conftest.exe conftest a.exe a_out.exe b.out conftest.*
```

Unas líneas más antes, veo que intenta recorrer esa lista, y al primer archivo `.c` falla:

```
for ac_file in $ac_files ''
do
  test -f "$ac_file" || continue
    echo -e "\n $PWD ac_file: $ac_file\n" # Agregué esta línea para mostrarlo
```

El archivo es:

```
/initrd/mnt/dev_save/sfs/gcc-12-20210530 ac_file: conftest.c
```

Fui a buscar el archivo y el archivo no existe, pero sí existe otro con un nombre muy parecido.

```
/gcc-12-20210530/gcc/testsuite/gcc.dg/analyzer/torture/conftest-1.c
```

Quise compilarlo como ejecutable pero la salida del *GCC 11* es totalmente diferente a lo que yo esperaba.

***conftest-1.c***

```
#include <stdio.h>
int
main ()
{
  FILE *f = fopen ("conftest.out", "w");
  return ferror (f) || fclose (f) != 0;

  ;
  return 0;
}
```

Para compilarlo como ejecutable hago lo siguiente:

```
cd /initrd/mnt/dev_save/sfs/gcc-12-20210530/gcc/testsuite/gcc.dg/analyzer/torture
gcc ./conftest-1.c -o ./conftest
```

La salida no es un binario como yo esperaba, es un archivo de texto plano:

```
# 0 "./conftest-1.c"
# 0 "<built-in>"
# 0 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 0 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "./conftest-1.c"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 1 3 4
# 27 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 3 4
# 1 "/usr/include/bits/libc-header-start.h" 1 3 4
# 33 "/usr/include/bits/libc-header-start.h" 3 4
# 1 "/usr/include/features.h" 1 3 4
# 473 "/usr/include/features.h" 3 4
# 1 "/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h" 1 3 4
# 462 "/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h" 3 4
# 1 "/usr/include/bits/wordsize.h" 1 3 4
# 463 "/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h" 2 3 4
# 1 "/usr/include/bits/long-double.h" 1 3 4
# 464 "/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h" 2 3 4
# 474 "/usr/include/features.h" 2 3 4
# 497 "/usr/include/features.h" 3 4
# 1 "/usr/include/gnu/stubs.h" 1 3 4
# 10 "/usr/include/gnu/stubs.h" 3 4
# 1 "/usr/include/gnu/stubs-64.h" 1 3 4
# 11 "/usr/include/gnu/stubs.h" 2 3 4
# 498 "/usr/include/features.h" 2 3 4
# 34 "/usr/include/bits/libc-header-start.h" 2 3 4
# 28 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 2 3 4





# 1 "/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.0.1/include/stddef.h" 1 3 4
# 209 "/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.0.1/include/stddef.h" 3 4

# 209 "/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.0.1/include/stddef.h" 3 4
typedef long unsigned int size_t;
# 34 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 2 3 4


# 1 "/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.0.1/include/stdarg.h" 1 3 4
# 40 "/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.0.1/include/stdarg.h" 3 4
typedef __builtin_va_list __gnuc_va_list;
# 37 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 2 3 4

# 1 "/usr/include/bits/types.h" 1 3 4
# 27 "/usr/include/bits/types.h" 3 4
# 1 "/usr/include/bits/wordsize.h" 1 3 4
# 28 "/usr/include/bits/types.h" 2 3 4
# 1 "/usr/include/bits/timesize.h" 1 3 4
# 29 "/usr/include/bits/types.h" 2 3 4


typedef unsigned char __u_char;
typedef unsigned short int __u_short;
typedef unsigned int __u_int;
typedef unsigned long int __u_long;


typedef signed char __int8_t;
typedef unsigned char __uint8_t;
typedef signed short int __int16_t;
typedef unsigned short int __uint16_t;
typedef signed int __int32_t;
typedef unsigned int __uint32_t;

typedef signed long int __int64_t;
typedef unsigned long int __uint64_t;






typedef __int8_t __int_least8_t;
typedef __uint8_t __uint_least8_t;
typedef __int16_t __int_least16_t;
typedef __uint16_t __uint_least16_t;
typedef __int32_t __int_least32_t;
typedef __uint32_t __uint_least32_t;
typedef __int64_t __int_least64_t;
typedef __uint64_t __uint_least64_t;



typedef long int __quad_t;
typedef unsigned long int __u_quad_t;







typedef long int __intmax_t;
typedef unsigned long int __uintmax_t;
# 141 "/usr/include/bits/types.h" 3 4
# 1 "/usr/include/bits/typesizes.h" 1 3 4
# 142 "/usr/include/bits/types.h" 2 3 4
# 1 "/usr/include/bits/time64.h" 1 3 4
# 143 "/usr/include/bits/types.h" 2 3 4


typedef unsigned long int __dev_t;
typedef unsigned int __uid_t;
typedef unsigned int __gid_t;
typedef unsigned long int __ino_t;
typedef unsigned long int __ino64_t;
typedef unsigned int __mode_t;
typedef unsigned long int __nlink_t;
typedef long int __off_t;
typedef long int __off64_t;
typedef int __pid_t;
typedef struct { int __val[2]; } __fsid_t;
typedef long int __clock_t;
typedef unsigned long int __rlim_t;
typedef unsigned long int __rlim64_t;
typedef unsigned int __id_t;
typedef long int __time_t;
typedef unsigned int __useconds_t;
typedef long int __suseconds_t;
typedef long int __suseconds64_t;

typedef int __daddr_t;
typedef int __key_t;


typedef int __clockid_t;


typedef void * __timer_t;


typedef long int __blksize_t;




typedef long int __blkcnt_t;
typedef long int __blkcnt64_t;


typedef unsigned long int __fsblkcnt_t;
typedef unsigned long int __fsblkcnt64_t;


typedef unsigned long int __fsfilcnt_t;
typedef unsigned long int __fsfilcnt64_t;


typedef long int __fsword_t;

typedef long int __ssize_t;


typedef long int __syscall_slong_t;

typedef unsigned long int __syscall_ulong_t;



typedef __off64_t __loff_t;
typedef char *__caddr_t;


typedef long int __intptr_t;


typedef unsigned int __socklen_t;




typedef int __sig_atomic_t;
# 39 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 2 3 4
# 1 "/usr/include/bits/types/__fpos_t.h" 1 3 4




# 1 "/usr/include/bits/types/__mbstate_t.h" 1 3 4
# 13 "/usr/include/bits/types/__mbstate_t.h" 3 4
typedef struct
{
  int __count;
  union
  {
    unsigned int __wch;
    char __wchb[4];
  } __value;
} __mbstate_t;
# 6 "/usr/include/bits/types/__fpos_t.h" 2 3 4




typedef struct _G_fpos_t
{
  __off_t __pos;
  __mbstate_t __state;
} __fpos_t;
# 40 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 2 3 4
# 1 "/usr/include/bits/types/__fpos64_t.h" 1 3 4
# 10 "/usr/include/bits/types/__fpos64_t.h" 3 4
typedef struct _G_fpos64_t
{
  __off64_t __pos;
  __mbstate_t __state;
} __fpos64_t;
# 41 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 2 3 4
# 1 "/usr/include/bits/types/__FILE.h" 1 3 4



struct _IO_FILE;
typedef struct _IO_FILE __FILE;
# 42 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 2 3 4
# 1 "/usr/include/bits/types/FILE.h" 1 3 4



struct _IO_FILE;


typedef struct _IO_FILE FILE;
# 43 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 2 3 4
# 1 "/usr/include/bits/types/struct_FILE.h" 1 3 4
# 35 "/usr/include/bits/types/struct_FILE.h" 3 4
struct _IO_FILE;
struct _IO_marker;
struct _IO_codecvt;
struct _IO_wide_data;




typedef void _IO_lock_t;





struct _IO_FILE
{
  int _flags;


  char *_IO_read_ptr;
  char *_IO_read_end;
  char *_IO_read_base;
  char *_IO_write_base;
  char *_IO_write_ptr;
  char *_IO_write_end;
  char *_IO_buf_base;
  char *_IO_buf_end;


  char *_IO_save_base;
  char *_IO_backup_base;
  char *_IO_save_end;

  struct _IO_marker *_markers;

  struct _IO_FILE *_chain;

  int _fileno;
  int _flags2;
  __off_t _old_offset;


  unsigned short _cur_column;
  signed char _vtable_offset;
  char _shortbuf[1];

  _IO_lock_t *_lock;







  __off64_t _offset;

  struct _IO_codecvt *_codecvt;
  struct _IO_wide_data *_wide_data;
  struct _IO_FILE *_freeres_list;
  void *_freeres_buf;
  size_t __pad5;
  int _mode;

  char _unused2[15 * sizeof (int) - 4 * sizeof (void *) - sizeof (size_t)];
};
# 44 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 2 3 4
# 52 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 3 4
typedef __gnuc_va_list va_list;
# 63 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 3 4
typedef __off_t off_t;
# 77 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 3 4
typedef __ssize_t ssize_t;






typedef __fpos_t fpos_t;
# 133 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 3 4
# 1 "/usr/include/bits/stdio_lim.h" 1 3 4
# 134 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 2 3 4



extern FILE *stdin;
extern FILE *stdout;
extern FILE *stderr;






extern int remove (const char *__filename) __attribute__ ((__nothrow__ , __leaf__));

extern int rename (const char *__old, const char *__new) __attribute__ ((__nothrow__ , __leaf__));



extern int renameat (int __oldfd, const char *__old, int __newfd,
       const char *__new) __attribute__ ((__nothrow__ , __leaf__));
# 173 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 3 4
extern FILE *tmpfile (void) ;
# 187 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 3 4
extern char *tmpnam (char *__s) __attribute__ ((__nothrow__ , __leaf__)) ;




extern char *tmpnam_r (char *__s) __attribute__ ((__nothrow__ , __leaf__)) ;
# 204 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 3 4
extern char *tempnam (const char *__dir, const char *__pfx)
     __attribute__ ((__nothrow__ , __leaf__)) __attribute__ ((__malloc__)) ;







extern int fclose (FILE *__stream);




extern int fflush (FILE *__stream);
# 227 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 3 4
extern int fflush_unlocked (FILE *__stream);
# 246 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 3 4
extern FILE *fopen (const char *__restrict __filename,
      const char *__restrict __modes) ;




extern FILE *freopen (const char *__restrict __filename,
        const char *__restrict __modes,
        FILE *__restrict __stream) ;
# 279 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 3 4
extern FILE *fdopen (int __fd, const char *__modes) __attribute__ ((__nothrow__ , __leaf__)) ;
# 292 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 3 4
extern FILE *fmemopen (void *__s, size_t __len, const char *__modes)
  __attribute__ ((__nothrow__ , __leaf__)) ;




extern FILE *open_memstream (char **__bufloc, size_t *__sizeloc) __attribute__ ((__nothrow__ , __leaf__)) ;





extern void setbuf (FILE *__restrict __stream, char *__restrict __buf) __attribute__ ((__nothrow__ , __leaf__));



extern int setvbuf (FILE *__restrict __stream, char *__restrict __buf,
      int __modes, size_t __n) __attribute__ ((__nothrow__ , __leaf__));




extern void setbuffer (FILE *__restrict __stream, char *__restrict __buf,
         size_t __size) __attribute__ ((__nothrow__ , __leaf__));


extern void setlinebuf (FILE *__stream) __attribute__ ((__nothrow__ , __leaf__));







extern int fprintf (FILE *__restrict __stream,
      const char *__restrict __format, ...);




extern int printf (const char *__restrict __format, ...);

extern int sprintf (char *__restrict __s,
      const char *__restrict __format, ...) __attribute__ ((__nothrow__));





extern int vfprintf (FILE *__restrict __s, const char *__restrict __format,
       __gnuc_va_list __arg);




extern int vprintf (const char *__restrict __format, __gnuc_va_list __arg);

extern int vsprintf (char *__restrict __s, const char *__restrict __format,
       __gnuc_va_list __arg) __attribute__ ((__nothrow__));



extern int snprintf (char *__restrict __s, size_t __maxlen,
       const char *__restrict __format, ...)
     __attribute__ ((__nothrow__)) __attribute__ ((__format__ (__printf__, 3, 4)));

extern int vsnprintf (char *__restrict __s, size_t __maxlen,
        const char *__restrict __format, __gnuc_va_list __arg)
     __attribute__ ((__nothrow__)) __attribute__ ((__format__ (__printf__, 3, 0)));
# 379 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 3 4
extern int vdprintf (int __fd, const char *__restrict __fmt,
       __gnuc_va_list __arg)
     __attribute__ ((__format__ (__printf__, 2, 0)));
extern int dprintf (int __fd, const char *__restrict __fmt, ...)
     __attribute__ ((__format__ (__printf__, 2, 3)));







extern int fscanf (FILE *__restrict __stream,
     const char *__restrict __format, ...) ;




extern int scanf (const char *__restrict __format, ...) ;

extern int sscanf (const char *__restrict __s,
     const char *__restrict __format, ...) __attribute__ ((__nothrow__ , __leaf__));





# 1 "/usr/include/bits/floatn.h" 1 3 4
# 119 "/usr/include/bits/floatn.h" 3 4
# 1 "/usr/include/bits/floatn-common.h" 1 3 4
# 24 "/usr/include/bits/floatn-common.h" 3 4
# 1 "/usr/include/bits/long-double.h" 1 3 4
# 25 "/usr/include/bits/floatn-common.h" 2 3 4
# 120 "/usr/include/bits/floatn.h" 2 3 4
# 407 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 2 3 4



extern int fscanf (FILE *__restrict __stream, const char *__restrict __format, ...) __asm__ ("" "__isoc99_fscanf")

                               ;
extern int scanf (const char *__restrict __format, ...) __asm__ ("" "__isoc99_scanf")
                              ;
extern int sscanf (const char *__restrict __s, const char *__restrict __format, ...) __asm__ ("" "__isoc99_sscanf") __attribute__ ((__nothrow__ , __leaf__))

                      ;
# 435 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 3 4
extern int vfscanf (FILE *__restrict __s, const char *__restrict __format,
      __gnuc_va_list __arg)
     __attribute__ ((__format__ (__scanf__, 2, 0))) ;





extern int vscanf (const char *__restrict __format, __gnuc_va_list __arg)
     __attribute__ ((__format__ (__scanf__, 1, 0))) ;


extern int vsscanf (const char *__restrict __s,
      const char *__restrict __format, __gnuc_va_list __arg)
     __attribute__ ((__nothrow__ , __leaf__)) __attribute__ ((__format__ (__scanf__, 2, 0)));





extern int vfscanf (FILE *__restrict __s, const char *__restrict __format, __gnuc_va_list __arg) __asm__ ("" "__isoc99_vfscanf")



     __attribute__ ((__format__ (__scanf__, 2, 0))) ;
extern int vscanf (const char *__restrict __format, __gnuc_va_list __arg) __asm__ ("" "__isoc99_vscanf")

     __attribute__ ((__format__ (__scanf__, 1, 0))) ;
extern int vsscanf (const char *__restrict __s, const char *__restrict __format, __gnuc_va_list __arg) __asm__ ("" "__isoc99_vsscanf") __attribute__ ((__nothrow__ , __leaf__))



     __attribute__ ((__format__ (__scanf__, 2, 0)));
# 489 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 3 4
extern int fgetc (FILE *__stream);
extern int getc (FILE *__stream);





extern int getchar (void);






extern int getc_unlocked (FILE *__stream);
extern int getchar_unlocked (void);
# 514 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 3 4
extern int fgetc_unlocked (FILE *__stream);
# 525 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 3 4
extern int fputc (int __c, FILE *__stream);
extern int putc (int __c, FILE *__stream);





extern int putchar (int __c);
# 541 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 3 4
extern int fputc_unlocked (int __c, FILE *__stream);







extern int putc_unlocked (int __c, FILE *__stream);
extern int putchar_unlocked (int __c);






extern int getw (FILE *__stream);


extern int putw (int __w, FILE *__stream);







extern char *fgets (char *__restrict __s, int __n, FILE *__restrict __stream)
     __attribute__ ((__access__ (__write_only__, 1, 2)));
# 608 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 3 4
extern __ssize_t __getdelim (char **__restrict __lineptr,
                             size_t *__restrict __n, int __delimiter,
                             FILE *__restrict __stream) ;
extern __ssize_t getdelim (char **__restrict __lineptr,
                           size_t *__restrict __n, int __delimiter,
                           FILE *__restrict __stream) ;







extern __ssize_t getline (char **__restrict __lineptr,
                          size_t *__restrict __n,
                          FILE *__restrict __stream) ;







extern int fputs (const char *__restrict __s, FILE *__restrict __stream);





extern int puts (const char *__s);






extern int ungetc (int __c, FILE *__stream);






extern size_t fread (void *__restrict __ptr, size_t __size,
       size_t __n, FILE *__restrict __stream) ;




extern size_t fwrite (const void *__restrict __ptr, size_t __size,
        size_t __n, FILE *__restrict __s);
# 678 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 3 4
extern size_t fread_unlocked (void *__restrict __ptr, size_t __size,
         size_t __n, FILE *__restrict __stream) ;
extern size_t fwrite_unlocked (const void *__restrict __ptr, size_t __size,
          size_t __n, FILE *__restrict __stream);







extern int fseek (FILE *__stream, long int __off, int __whence);




extern long int ftell (FILE *__stream) ;




extern void rewind (FILE *__stream);
# 712 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 3 4
extern int fseeko (FILE *__stream, __off_t __off, int __whence);




extern __off_t ftello (FILE *__stream) ;
# 736 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 3 4
extern int fgetpos (FILE *__restrict __stream, fpos_t *__restrict __pos);




extern int fsetpos (FILE *__stream, const fpos_t *__pos);
# 762 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 3 4
extern void clearerr (FILE *__stream) __attribute__ ((__nothrow__ , __leaf__));

extern int feof (FILE *__stream) __attribute__ ((__nothrow__ , __leaf__)) ;

extern int ferror (FILE *__stream) __attribute__ ((__nothrow__ , __leaf__)) ;



extern void clearerr_unlocked (FILE *__stream) __attribute__ ((__nothrow__ , __leaf__));
extern int feof_unlocked (FILE *__stream) __attribute__ ((__nothrow__ , __leaf__)) ;
extern int ferror_unlocked (FILE *__stream) __attribute__ ((__nothrow__ , __leaf__)) ;







extern void perror (const char *__s);




extern int fileno (FILE *__stream) __attribute__ ((__nothrow__ , __leaf__)) ;




extern int fileno_unlocked (FILE *__stream) __attribute__ ((__nothrow__ , __leaf__)) ;
# 799 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 3 4
extern FILE *popen (const char *__command, const char *__modes) ;





extern int pclose (FILE *__stream);





extern char *ctermid (char *__s) __attribute__ ((__nothrow__ , __leaf__));
# 839 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 3 4
extern void flockfile (FILE *__stream) __attribute__ ((__nothrow__ , __leaf__));



extern int ftrylockfile (FILE *__stream) __attribute__ ((__nothrow__ , __leaf__)) ;


extern void funlockfile (FILE *__stream) __attribute__ ((__nothrow__ , __leaf__));
# 857 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 3 4
extern int __uflow (FILE *);
extern int __overflow (FILE *, int);
# 874 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 3 4

# 2 "./conftest-1.c" 2

# 2 "./conftest-1.c"
int
main ()
{
  FILE *f = fopen ("conftest.out", "w");
  return ferror (f) || fclose (f) != 0;

  ;
  return 0;
}
```

¿Qué me puede estar faltando para que compile bien? También veo extraño que me diga eso del comando `sed`, ya que tengo la última versión.

Answer (score 0):

El binario `gcc` no es el indicado, hay que usar `x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc-11.0.1`:

Primero hay que cambiarle el nombre a los cuatro `gcc` que están mal, para no perderlos:

```
cd /bin
mv ./cpp ./cpp2
mv ./gcc ./gcc2
mv ./c++ ./c++2
mv ./g++ ./g++2
```

Luego hacer un enlace simbólico al `gcc` real:

```
cd /bin
ln -svf x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc-11.0.1 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc
```

Y por último hacer los cuatro enlaces simbólicos con los nombres simplificados:

```
ln -sfv x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc-11.0.1 cpp
ln -sfv x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc-11.0.1 gcc
ln -sfv x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc-11.0.1 c++
ln -sfv x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc-11.0.1 g++
```

De esta manera ya el *GCC* puede compilar... Por último, hay que intentar nuevamente configurar el *GCC 12*:

```
cd /gcc-12-20210530/
./configure
```

Nota: El sistema de archivos *FAT* no soporta enlaces simbólicos, hacerlo en *Ext2*, *Ext3* o *Ext4*.